# OpenLdap LDAP admin group ALC

Tags: openldap

I have the following LDIF file to create ldapadmins.

```
dn: ou=Manager,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Manager

dn: ou=Customers,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Customers

dn: cn=customerAccountAdmin,ou=Manager,dc=example,dc=org
cn: customerAccountAdmin
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: top
userPassword: {SSHA}*removed*

dn: ou=Users,ou=Customers,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Users

dn: ou=Groups,ou=Customers,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Groups
```

I created the following ldif to allow multiple admins for phpldap admin. (they will manage multiple customers)

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * by self read by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn.base="cn=customerAccountAdmin,ou=Manager,dc=example,dc=org" write
```

Afer logging in to the phpldap admin the customerAccountAdmin cannot see the tree. but from the ALC view it should have every permission.

Do i miss something?
Is it easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the order in which the `access` directives are evaluated:

> Within this priority, access directives are examined in the order in which they appear in the config file. Slapd stops with the **first** `<what>` selector that matches the entry and/or attribute. The corresponding access directive is the one slapd will use to evaluate access.

(cf. [Access Control Evaluation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#Access%20Control%20Evaluation)). That means that your second `to *` directive is never evaluated and the first one applies to all entries.

You should modify the access rules to look like:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
olcAccess: to *
  by self read
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by dn.base="cn=customerAccountAdmin,ou=Manager,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by * none
```

An alternative (which combines with your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/q/1003900/530633)) is to create a `cn=Administrators,dc=example,dc=org` group and give write access to everything to the members of this group:

```
dn: cn=Administrators,dc=example,dc=org
changetype: add
cn: Administrators
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=customerAccountAdmin,ou=Manager,dc=example,dc=org
member: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.exact="cn=Administrators,dc=example,dc=org"
  by dn.exact="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by group.exact="cn=Administrators,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
olcAccess: to *
  by self read
  by group.exact="cn=Administrators,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by * none
```

EDIT: Worth mentioning, it is important that you use `replace: olcAccess` or delete before adding if you're still using the default `olcAccess`. `add: olcAccess` without removing the default `olcAccess` does not work since it won't override it.